# Powershell - Change variables based on CSV file

Tags: variables, powershell, csv, wmi

I'm attempting to use a CSV file for automatic computer naming with powershell.  Our Computer names carry general model numbers which tell me the actual type of computer.  For instance, Model # 2537CU1 is a Lenovo T410.  I want to pull the model number and change the variable to T410.

I can already get the model number with a get-wmiobject call to the computersystem class, but to create a variable with the "type" data, like T410 I'm having to use a bunch of If, and elseif statements.  This is due to the sheer number or models/types we support.  My goal is to have a CSV to edit instead of the script itself. I just want the corresponding Model to get the right variable for the "type" of machine.

So here's where my head is so far and I know I'm way off:

```
$model = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | select -ExpandProperty Model
$modelCSV = "0"
$typeCSV = "0"
Import-Csv -Path "C:\TechDiv\ComputerModel_Type.csv" |
ForEach-Object {
    $modelCSV += $_.Model
    $typeCSV += $_.Type
    }
if ($modelCSV -like $model)
   {
        $model = $typeCSV
    }
```

Where my CSV looks like this:

```
Model, Type
0401B7U, A70Z
0401R6U, A70Z
1165A3U, A70Z
25521H8, 0E31
2552Ck1, 0E31
7360, 0M58
7483, 0M58
7630, 0M58
```

Ultimately my computer naming script will concatenate the model and serial number for easy collections and updates.  Example with model/serial name (0's pad the left serial to fill 10 spaces):  T410000R84D06Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
$model = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | select -ExpandProperty Model
$modelCSV = "0"
$typeCSV = "0"
$modelList = Import-Csv -Path "C:\TechDiv\ComputerModel_Type.csv" |
$modelName = $modelList | Where-Object{$_.Model -eq $model}
```

Comment: How do I translate the "Model" that the WMI call brings and change to "Type" from the CSV.  The Type is what I really want.  So the WMI call gives me 3257CU1 (model), for instance.  I want that to translate my variable to T410 (type).

Comment: I used your Where-Object line and went a little further since I needed the "Type" information to come across.  Posting the code in an answer below since replies can't have code snippets.

Comment: $model = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | select -ExpandProperty Model
$modelType = Import-Csv -Path "C:\TechDiv\ComputerModel_Type.csv" | Where-Object {$_.Model -eq $model} | select -ExpandProperty type

Answer (score 0):

I'd load that CSV into a hash table:

```
$ModelHash = @{}
Import-Csv -Path "C:\TechDiv\ComputerModel_Type.csv" |
ForEach-Object { $ModelHash[$_.Model = $_.Type }

$model = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | select -ExpandProperty Model

$Type = $ModelHash[$Model]
```